# Switching the GND of a Wheatstone bridge using NPN

Tags: analog, npn, wheatstone-bridge

I am trying to turn on and off the power supply to this bridge by using a micro controller.
Can I use the following switch using an NPN ?

[image: Schematics]

Edit:
A switch using a MOSFET - a better option?
[image]

Comment: Have you calculated the current and voltage drop? 3.3V @ 27 Ohm gices 120mA current. While the 10k base resistor would pass cca. 270 micro amps. You would need a beta higher than 500.

Comment: *"Edit: A switch using a MOSFET - a better option? "* Not this one, since it is a PMOS.

Comment: Nch arrow points inward.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad idea for a couple reasons. The BJT would need a lot of gain (or a lot of base drive) to be fully saturated as @Marco notes. The BJT will still have a relatively large voltage drop which will reduce the sensitivity of your bridge by maybe 5%, and that value will not be particularly stable.

I suggest  using a logic-level MOSFET instead. Even an amazingly inexpensive [AO3400](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/ao3400.pdf) will have an Rds(on) in the 30m\$\Omega\$ range with 3.3V drive which would drop only about 4mV, so  have an effect in the ~0.1% range.

Answer (score 0):

With a load of 27 Ohms you only need 270 Ohms base resistance (10x Rc load) to saturate the transistor, then the Common Mode attenuation of your INA with  Vce(sat) variations will be quite small after null calibration the gain error is similar to supply voltage tolerance and will add a < 1% gain error, with offset error calibrated out.

If you calibrate for gain error and have tight tolerance on the supply or have ADC Vref = Vcc then the gain error from Vcc can be nulled out.

But it depends on your differential gain and range and thus the CMRR vs the dynamic resolution and desired accuracy of your ADC results with any drift in temperature of the Vce(sat) and CM attenuation.

Without knowing (ALL) your design goals, it's hard to say, but if it's doable but RR6 = 10k is certainly wrong.

### Conclusion:

- You need more Design Specs for error tolerance
- then verify gain and offset errors with calibration.
- switch voltage saturation contributes some gain error but offset is nulled by CMRR and null calibration.
- it is doable, but you need to do a design spec for Error tolerances then design it, then verify it.. (Not trial and error and fix later)
- the resistor error value was minor boo boo.

### recommendation

the PN2222A types are < 1 Ohm while others may be ~ 4 Ohms for Rce=Vce(sat)/Ic, so you consider cost, switch voltage gain error and supply drift voltage errors with environmental stresses.  But  FET choice is certainly a lower RdsOn but more pesos. ;)

In the end it is not how many mV is across the switch because the 3.3V regulator may be 1% which is a bigger source of error. It is how you null gain error with some calibration and how stable is the net voltage drop with temperature.